# In MySQL If 'CURDATE' is today, what is tomorrow?

Tags: mysql, email, easyphp, .aspxauth

I want bookings for tomorrow to receive an auto-email as a reminder, but I'm unsure how to only send to tomorrows clients.

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM enquiries where emailaddress > '' and bookingdate = CURDATE() and statusbar <> 'calledtoconfirm' and lang_code = 'EN' "
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM enquiries where emailaddress = '' "
rs.Open strSQL, adoCon
```

I'm working on a live site, so to test it would be to send hundreds of emails.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: emailaddress > '' or should you be testing is null ? Please add table definition as text and/or confirm bookingdate is date/datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get the bookings for tomorrow

Just change the following clause in your current query using [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function

```
   AND bookingdate = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```